# Can many universes exist inside black holes?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity

As temperature and pressure grows, matter changes. The energy imposed on matter forces particles to disintegrate and recombine in different ways and subatomic orbitals fold over each other into new, smaller and faster patterns.

Because a black hole contains millions of different compression levels, can it be said that the matter inside a black hole will transition between millions of different states and dimensions.

As the temperature forces subatomic particles to vibrate much faster, in the space of one nanosecond inside the black hole, 10 billion years would occur in a planet far away.

Amateur scientist question sorry: If matter could recombine into many different states of orbital equilibrium and timescales inside a black hole, does that not mean they are engines for creating durable universes that slowly transition from one state of matter to another? they are universe generators?

I like that theory because it means that the universe is a self replicating structure, which is a natural law of presence and of creation.

Comment: It's tempting to want to close this, but it's not completely crazy. You did pick the wrong system, though. It's completely impossible, at the moment, to make any scientifically relevant statement about the interior of black holes. Had you chosen neutron stars, instead, then I would have agreed with you. They represent a very hot, very dense state of matter. They  have strong thermal gradients and magnetic "weather" systems on their surfaces. They do represent matter that is potentially capable of phase transitions at extremely short time scales. Say "neutron star" and I will say "maybe".

Comment: For myself i would say universes, it sounded more logical to say universe generators. Isn't it possible to theorize that particles will never be static at any compression level and will always change orbitals into as many states of matter as there are compressions gradients?

Comment: There is, by definition, only one universe. We may be prevented by event horizons from seeing all of it, but there is still only one universe. Now, if you want to be adamant about black holes, which nobody knows anything about, really, then you are still left with a problem: in general relativity there seems to be a prediction that does create such an internal one way wormhole to another region, but it doesn't seem to be a stable solution. Charge and angular momentum, if I believe, close this "wormhole". I don't think that GR is the correct theory, but not even GR does what you need.

Comment: It seems like a mathematical principle of sine waves to say that complexity-itself deepens as frequencies bounce and deviate one another based on their distance from each other same as sine wave frequency-modulation transforms, what would the generation of complexity from simpler wave imply? It's so mathematical because it just multiplies and changes the sine waves themselves into different equilibria, say the layers of the onion to the singularity are like very fast sine waves always changing states and complexity, i don't know how to apply physics to that mathematical view.

Answer (score 2):

> As temperature and pressure grows, matter changes. The energy imposed on matter forces particles to disintegrate and recombine in different ways...

OK..

> and subatomic orbitals fold over each other into new, smaller and faster patterns.

I don't think you can give an example of this.

> Because a black hole contains millions of different compression levels,

Not really.

> can it be said that the matter inside a black hole will transition between millions of different states and dimensions.

It can be said that matter that falls inside a black hole will experience incredible stresses as it approaches toward the singularity. Beyond that is speculation rather than physics.

> in the space of one nanosecond inside the black hole, 10 billion years would occur in a planet far away.

That particular ratio of time-dilation occurs at a location still slightly outside of the event horizon.

> Amateur scientist question sorry: If matter could recombine into many different states of orbital equilibrium and timescales ...

In science you generally want to avoid premising a hypothetical on poorly-defined and counterfactual theories. If instead you were to study what *is* known about your topic of interest, you could learn to calculate the answer to interesting questions such as: if a lump of matter falls into a black hole, does it compress, or does it stretch and dilute?

Comment: Confinement of waves results in an increase in complexity of the patterns which is exponential because they interact a lot more... and i thought that the generation of harmonic complexity within an event horizon sounds fun.    _I don't think you can give an example of this... if you play sine waves in a large room the resulting waves are simpler than in a smaller room, why do you think subatomic particle trajectories behave unlike all other known waves?

Comment: Consider various cubic rooms, differing in size. If I measure sound wavelength in units of room length, there is no difference in the way that sound waves propagate in these rooms, and there is certainly not an exponential increase in complexity. (As for subatomic trajectories, "unlike" in what way precisely?)

Comment: Confine some waves in a smaller space and their paths cross more often and at more complex angles and in a smaller amount of time. Make two waves in a football sized wave-tank and their paths will cross at simple angles, you can will simple interpretable patterns in the water for minutes until it becomes chaos, make the same wave in a table tennis sized tank and the waves will encounter reflections of reflections of interactions with each other very fast and it will become chaos in a few seconds. it's the same principle in all trigonometry and a result of irrationals and squaring circles.

Comment: if you divide an irrational number with whole numbers or irrational numbers into slices, you just get a huge array of different irrational numbers, created from the original numbers, and confining waves causes the irrational the number PI and other irrationals to interact at very high frequencies, so making waves interact more generates complexity as a function of the volume of confinement.

Comment: Time stops at the surface of the black hole, and yet sequences of events occur inside the black hole, so our universe is split at the boundary, and an entirely exotic time exists inside, and we would be unreasonable to say that there isn't a gradient of radius within the black hole which will have different physical properties and therefore layers, so i don't agree with your presumption regarding there not being layers, it's unrealistic. if you say that matter approache the singularity you say that the waves will be superimposed together at different proximities unless particles become static.